# Layout in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts

Is it possible to create a 2 sided layout in ARCGIS so I can print on one sheet of paper(front and back of an A4 or A3 paper)?

I often find myself wanting to produce a number of different map outputs to be printed doubled sided on an A4 or A3 paper, and this requires printing to pdf on two different sheets and using the print setup with adobe to print on both sides.

I'm sure that ArcGIS will have something like this, but I can't seem to find how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use data driven pages to do this.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000002p000000

Comment: Be aware that this can take a while to run if you have more than a few pages, and requires two copies of your mxd.